# Multi upload with jquery SYMFONY2

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have a problem with multi file upload. I use a bundle [**LcnFileUploaderBundle**](https://github.com/FaiblUG/LcnFileUploaderBundle).

When I click `save` my file don't save in correct folder. I use function `syncFilesFromTemp`. When I change the function to `syncFilesToTemp` all is OK but save my files in temporary folder. My controller and `twig` files looks the same as in link.

Comment: Give us some more info. Maybe some code snippet or something like that?

Comment: Please investigate your upload folder name likely returned from here: $uploadFolderName = $this->getUploadFolderName($editId); Also investigate permissions if the files are not appearing as your web server may not be able to save to this folder unless you enable it too!

Answer (score 0):

my controller:

```
/**
 * Edit Uploads for the given entity id
 *
 * In a real world scenario you might want to check edit permissions
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $entityId
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, $entityId)
{
    $editId = intval($entityId);
    if ($editId < 1000000000) {
        throw new \Exception('invalid editId');
    }

    $fileUploader = $this->container->get('lcn.file_uploader');
   // $fileUploader1 = $this->container->get('lcn.file_manager');

    $uploadFolderName = $this->getUploadFolderName($editId);

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('lcn_file_uploader_demo_edit', array('entityId'  => $entityId)))
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->submit($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $fileUploader->syncFilesFromTemp($uploadFolderName);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('addItemGallery', array('entityId'  => $entityId)));
        }
    } else {
        $fileUploader->syncFilesToTemp($uploadFolderName);
    }

    return $this->render('PortfolioAdminBundle:Gallery:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entityId' => $entityId,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'uploadUrl' => $this->generateUrl('lcn_file_uploader_demo_handle_file_upload', array('entityId' => $entityId)),
        'uploadFolderName' => $uploadFolderName,
    ));
}
```

_

```
/**
 * Store the uploaded file.
 *
 * In a real world scenario you might probably want to check
 * if the user is allowed to store uploads for the given entity id.
 *
 * Delegates to LcnFileUploader which implements a REST Interface and handles file uploads as well as file deletions.
 *
 * This action must not return a response. The response is generated in native PHP by LcnFileUploader.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param int $userId
 */
public function handleFileUploadAction($entityId, Request $request)
{
    $entityId = intval($entityId);
    if ($entityId < 100000000) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Invalid edit id: '.$entityId);
    }
    $this->container->get('lcn.file_uploader')->handleFileUpload(array(
        'folder' => $this->getUploadFolderName($entityId),
        //'max_number_of_files' => 3, //overwrites parameter lcn_file_uploader.max_number_of_files
        //'allowed_extensions' => array('jpg'), //overwrites parameter lcn_file_uploader.allowed_extensions
        //'sizes' => array('thumbnail' => array('folder' => 'thumbnail', 'max_width' => 100, 'max_height' => 100, 'crop' => true), 'profile' => array('folder' => 'profile', 'max_width' => 400, 'max_height' => 400, 'crop' => true)), //overwrites parameter lcn_file_uploader.sizes
    ));
}
```

#

```
public function handleFileUpload($options = array())
{
    if (!isset($options['folder']))
    {
        throw new \Exception("You must pass the 'folder' option to distinguish this set of files from others");
    }

    $options = array_merge($this->options, $options);

    $allowedExtensions = $options['allowed_extensions'];

    // Build a regular expression like /(\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)$/i
    $allowedExtensionsRegex = '/(' . implode('|', array_map(function($extension) { return '\.' . $extension; }, $allowedExtensions)) . ')$/i';

    $sizes = (isset($options['sizes']) && is_array($options['sizes'])) ? $options['sizes'] : array();

    $tempFilePath = $options['temp_file_base_path'] . '/' . $options['folder'];
    $tempWebPath = $options['temp_web_base_path'] . '/' . $options['folder'];

    foreach ($sizes as $index => $size)
    {
        $sizes[$index]['upload_dir'] = $tempFilePath . '/' . $size['folder'] . '/';;
        $sizes[$index]['upload_url'] = $tempWebPath . '/' . $size['folder'] . '/';
        $sizes[$index]['no_cache'] = true;
    }

    $uploadDir = $tempFilePath . '/' . $this->getOriginalFolderName() . '/';;
    $uploadUrl = $tempWebPath . '/' . $this->getOriginalFolderName() . '/';

    foreach ($sizes as $size)
    {
        @mkdir($size['upload_dir'], 0777, true);
    }

    @mkdir($uploadDir, 0777, true);

    new $this->options['upload_handler_class'](
        array(
            'file_namers' => $options['file_namers'],
            'upload_dir' => $uploadDir, 
            'upload_url' => $uploadUrl,
            'image_versions' => $sizes,
            'accept_file_types' => $allowedExtensionsRegex,
            'max_number_of_files' => $options['max_number_of_files'],
            'max_file_size' => $options['max_file_size'],
        ));

    // Without this Symfony will try to respond; the BlueImp upload handler class already did,
    // so it's time to hush up
    exit(0);
}
```

and twig:

```
 {% block body %}
Demo usage of LcnFileUploaderBundle
```

Edit Uploads of temporary entity {{ entityId }}

{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'id': 'lcn-file-uploader-demo' } }) }}

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{% include 'PortfolioAdminBundle:Theme:lcnFileUploaderWidget.html.twig' with {
    'uploadUrl': uploadUrl,
    'uploadFolderName': uploadFolderName,
    'formSelector': '#lcn-file-uploader-demo'
} %}

{{ form_rest(form) }}

<input type="submit" value="save">
```

{% endblock %}

routing.yml

```
lcn_file_uploader_demo_handle_file_upload:
    path:     /admin/gallery/added-item/file-upload/{entityId}
    defaults: { _controller: PortfolioAdminBundle:Gallery:handleFileUpload }
lcn_file_uploader_demo_edit:
    path:     /admin/gallery/added-item/edit/{entityId}
    defaults: { _controller: PortfolioAdminBundle:Gallery:Edit }
lcn_file_uploader_demo_create:
    path:     /admin/gallery/added-item/add/
    defaults: { _controller: PortfolioAdminBundle:Gallery:Create }
addItemGallery:
     path:   /admin/gallery/added-item/{entityId}
     defaults:  { _controller: PortfolioAdminBundle:Gallery:AddItem }
```